# How to change my version of node using a script?

Tags: node.js, linux, unix, zsh, nvm

I'm trying to write scripts that allow me to switch my development environment.

I want to write a script so that I can call it like this:

`switchdevA`

and inside that script, one of the things it should do is switch to node v16.16.0

inside switchdevA i have the following:

```
#!/bin/zsh
source ~/.zshrc
nvm use v16.16.0
```

the output says that I have switched to node v16.16.0, but when I type `node -v` I get:

`v12.22.12`

I can fix if i call `source switchdevA`, but should I do it that way? Other things like java don't seem to require me sourcing. In addition, the installation is lost if I start a new zsh session, ideally it should install for the current session and all future sessions.

What's the best practice around this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick clarification: NVM is a shell function and not an executable.

You've correctly identified that `source switchdevA` will work properly, and that it is different from other version managers.

One solution is to keep your script as is, and create an additional shell alias that will run `source scriptname` (e.g. `alias switchdevA='source switchdevA'`).

Unfortunately, for your other request to keep the current Node version in all future shell sessions, that can’t be achieved unless you have some persistence added in. For example, a simple file named **~/.lastnode**.  Then, in your **~/.zshrc**, you would have a line `nvm use "$(cat ~/.lastnode)"` (which comes after the initialization of NVM).  Finally, the original script would need to include a line at the bottom to update the last selected Node version: `nvm version > ~/.lastnode`.